# Pange transition with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, mousewheel

I'm trying to implement in my website some sort of smooth full page transition using whether the mousewheel or a button, but I'm having some problems with it. The idea is to have basically the same as in http://www.flyjetedge.com/.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some of the code that you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any worth to post piece of code. Everything that I managed to do was to implement some smooth page jumps, but within the same page, which is not the point. :/

Comment: There are numerous plugins and tutorials that will help you. Qeestion is far too broad as it stands now

Comment: I managed the problem with a easy to implement and customize plug in.

Comment: Btw, if someone will eventually wish to add the same effect to their websites, this is the one I used. http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ Greetings and thanks for the help! ;)